# How can I add a legend to this Vega visualization

Tags: visualization, vega

I am trying to figure out how to add a legend to the example vega visualization [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/donut-chart/). Any example of how to do this would be appreciated. Preferably it would be interactive and highlight or show data on the visualization, but even just a simple legend would be a big improvement.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For a simple starting point using `legends` in this [Vega Donut Chart Demo](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/donut-chart/):**

### [Here's the same example Vega sandbox](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwAJgAMuxREgpG1fFr0GlkdKzzdYjAF7ItkGbNeGoj6jPQANrBaANpKEKAQUVD+qK44kLB46ABOeACCMtQBXuFRkBSBrPFgVtFG7IwyalrAkFWEdm4p6FleUKhVWgYd6AAeWgBsdNoAnPI+eMiE3XS6AIwAvnmL3hF5RrElkMjVmdm55VCFAcVDI+MbUJXVtfUyjXjNrdTtkJ1yOD3v-edjE4kpjMvnMlis1mBIuV3Og4m5COg1PscgorgUiiUytCbjUcHUGk0Ei02goOl0vgCMAMQWDoqs8lDojC4QkqjJkCkAEqIxisYIQownM44QZYpk4u4Ep5El5vD7dSm-HCjb5JaZaWlRenRRn5LZueDcFLsrk8vmoo7o06YgXXKq4yH3R7PEmU8mlRXUsDzVVA2YAVmWdIhdX1CWkaVJVuFYAAZoFYMgARK8U7CVAkMh4ABrdjcAaLINgAC63kganQyVCDLRYagyXYKNt0eQwRwYSOEXqDvmANjjGQAQdom1nfxDu0fYHQ6Go6O460AGYp4Oe7o5+UFzhRCuZzhFxudd2tP7dw6AOyHqJbsCDM9aAAcReipbReGJsFjRtQ1c7kKuTJ4AAnoQ2yEAOFp-lA-arm4MEzraTJJKkGRZCiqa+P4ARuMhaTIq4V5MrsSJoSUdSYYEbjEfhkCEfkEbSo6FHYeGRpPM+5QcRAxYrEor5GAggStr+161rC2yGgERqQYBIHbEaahVJRzZqNwGDunUFZVgkDZNtB04OseV6QMSrx3PwaASZWNBGkBei0bx3FlhgKTZm2YAdqJlrAaBbipPAMn5LGKRqXcWmYDp6CNgRza7IaahkQBUC7FMKS1ElRj9gELFMfAQkGtwUlpferI1HRRheuRphYW4qgaIgYCkDotGIfkQHmdVlEJCYZh4I1zVcVqrWQKwhBaYlUGTChNGpvBhm4ahBwtRlyV7KRdxzVRa1LeVUAIiRS0YZ1OWQPtNG7fcJrcop5pHX4XVQGyHLXbywQXdwdjPWa7lVfdJ11Sw-XaMtk2QIaxpfTdP2JMdBUQ6aUMOX+g0cUW-FQDkrzVO5nnrJaWUnZJ0nNngzDoVAAAqiCMLAYA02ALDIGAFNk4c0JGgOMiMe4niBUYcXcAl6V-okQGoHmQR3ClHIbYw2UAPIIvAzDtamQqYnQgaFsNARRYO0OjeNdxTH0jF1JtCTq7RhZXKjfEgIsQA) with my `legends` code from below added in after the `marks` section.

Here is the legend code I used:

```
  "legends": [
    {
      "fill": "color",
      "title": "This is the Title",
      "orient": "top-left",
      "encode": {
        "symbols": {"enter": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}},
        "labels": {"update": {"text": {"field": "value"}}}
      }
    }
  ]
```

This should serve as a useful example starting point for you. Other properties of `legends` can be [found here.](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/legends/)

Comment: Do you know where one puts this in the js version of the spec? i.e. vl.encode, vl.data etc.